# Dynamic variable inside à string

Tags: php

Is there a way to dynamically change a variable value inside a string?

What i have tryed :

```
$World= "World";
$world = &$World;
$tmp = "Hello ".$world." ====";

$World= "Tada!";

echo $tmp;
```

What it echoed : `Hello World ====`
what i want it to echo : `Hello Tada! ====`

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: Fix a stupid mistake... (KISS Version) let's say i have a function that echo a pattern of html and i want it to change dynamically, but i can't move the block inside the function, nor after the function.

Comment: @Charles: So, you want some templating system.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sortof yes. i usually don't use that kind of structure (too hard to modify), but this is for an old code i'm working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to dynamically change a variable value inside of a string?

No.

There is no more "variable inside of a string" after this line got executed, but just a regular string.

you may use some placeholder instead of interpolating a variable

```
$tmp   = "Hello %s ====";
$World = "World";
echo sprintf($tmp,$World);
$World = "Tada!";
echo sprintf($tmp,$World);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use str_replace

```
 $tml = "Hellow world!!!"
 echo (str_replace("world","TADA",$tmp));
```

Comment: hi, sorry to be late on my reply, here's where it's problematic. if i get `Hello world from world!` it will become `Hello TADA from TADA`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `eval()`:

```
$tmp = '$tmp = "Hello $world";';
$World= "Tada!";
eval($tmp);
echo $tmp;
```

Comment: hi, your answer would work. but using eval is a really bad practice. lot of security issues.